Heine-Borel for Finite Dimensional Normed Vector Spaces
I would like to show that finite-dimensional normed vector spaces have the Heine-Borel property (any subset is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded). I have decided to take the following approach:

Show compact implies closed and bounded (I used Hausdorffness to show closedness, and definitions to show boundedness)
Show that for any normed vector space $(X, \vert\vert{\cdot}\vert\vert)$ of dimension $n$, there is a homeomorphism $T: (X, \vert\vert{\cdot}\vert\vert) \to (\mathbb{R}^n, \vert\vert{\cdot}\vert\vert_\infty)$.
Show Heine-Borel for $\mathbb{R}^n$ (say, Rudin's proof in his "Principles" textbook, for example).
Show the preservation of closedness, boundedness and compactness by the homeomorphism $T$ in Step 2, concluding the proof.

In Step 2, while I am able to show bijectivity and continuity of the inverse of $T$, where I define $T$ canonically as taking $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i$ to $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i e_i$, where $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ is a chosen (and fixed) basis of $X$ and $\{e_i | i \in \{1, \dots, n\}\}$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, I am unable to directly show continuity of $T$.
Note that I do not want to use more advanced results, unless it doesn't assume Bolzano-Weierstrass or Heine-Borel. For instance, I do not want to show that finite-dimensional normed vector spaces are Banach spaces, and using the linearity of $T$ and the continuity of $T^{-1}$ to conclude that $T$ is a homeomorphism by the Open Mapping Theorem, unless all of the intermediate steps can be easily achieved without compactness results or further related work.
The best would be a direct $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof of continuity of $T$ which I don't seem able to come up with.

which definition of equivalence of norms are you using? anyway, this is not a complicated result; it only uses Heine-Borel, no need for open-mapping or Banach’s isomorphism theorem or anything like that.

I agree- the title was not well-chosen. I have changed it to reflect the question better. The question is now as posed above- in particular, proving the continuity of the map $T$. Thank you.

in order to prove continuity of $T$, you need some form of the equivalence of norms (which uses Heine-Borel, i.e compactness), but you seem to be saying you don’t want to use compactness results, so this is sort of unanswerable.

would you instead be happy with a logical proof of all the relevant results in this direction (it’s really not that long, and the only real results we need are some basic equivalences of continuity of linear maps, and Heine-Borel)?

I see- interesting. Do you have intuition for why that is? Also, how would you prove Heine-Borel for finite dimensional normed vector spaces? If you want to pass to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and prove it there, that seems fine, but won't the "passing to" actually mean constructing a homeomorphism (which is what I am stuck on)?

Indeed. As long as the proof-structure doesn't use a result without proving it first, I would be happy with it. My problem is that with the structure I have chosen, I seem to be forced to use things that I ultimately am trying to prove (or at least, I am not able to see other ways of doing it).

I mean, you could just prove step 3 first. Then the compactness from 3 would be enough to imply 2. (Just consider the unit sphere of $(\mathbb{R}^n, |\cdot|\infty)$. Then continuity of inverse of $T$ means $|T^{-1}(\cdot)|$ is a continuous function on it. By compactness, the minimum of the range is achieved, and this minimum $C$ must be strictly positive since $T^{-1}$ is injective and $|\cdot|$ is a norm, so for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $|x|\infty = 1$ implies $|T^{-1}(x)| \geq C$. This implies $|Ty|_\infty \leq \frac{1}{C}|y|$ for all $y \in X$, so $T$ is continuous.)

Our goal is to prove Heine-Borel for an arbitrary $n$-dimensional normed-vector space $X$ by assuming Heine-Borel in $\Bbb{R}^n$. So, what I really want is a map $f:X\to\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $f$ sends closed bounded sets in $X$ to closed bounded sets in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and such that $f^{-1}$ is continuous, because then given a closed bounded $C\subset X$, I know $f(C)$ is closed bounded in $\Bbb{R}^n$, hence compact, hence $C=f^{-1}[f(C)]$ is compact. But really how do we show the existence of such an $f$? The easiest is to use a linear one, and prove it has the properties using equivalence of norm

@peek-a-boo Such an $f$ is necessarily a linear homeomorphism, and to construct one you need to prove Heine-Borel for one of the spaces first. So it’s just about proving step 3 before step 2 anyway.

@DavidGao I don't quite follow your answer on proving Step 3 first. In particular, my problem  is with the claim that C > 0. Since $T^{-1}$, as defined, is linear, won't it take $0$ from the unit-sphere to $0 \in X$? And by positive-definiteness of $\vert\vert\cdot\vert\vert$, $\vert\vert0\vert\vert = 0$, so, the minimum of the range is $0$. I probably have just completely misunderstood something, but would be glad for an explanation.

@peek-a-boo The use of equivalence of the norms is the problem- at least, I am not aware of how to prove it without Heine-Borel.

@TreadCarefully I meant the unit sphere, that is, the set of elements of norm exactly $1$, or symbolically, ${x \in \mathbb{R}^n: |x|_\infty = 1}$, not the unit ball (which is the set of elements of norm less than or equal to $1$).

Throughout, let $\Bbb{F}$ be either $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$. Recall that if $X,Y$ are normed vector spaces over $\Bbb{F}$ and $T:X\to Y$ is linear, then the following statements are equivalent:

$T$ is bounded near the origin
$T$ is continuous at the origin
$T$ is continuous everywhere
$T$ is Lipschitz continuous
there is an $M>0$ such that for all $x\in X$, $\|T(x)\|_Y\leq M\|x\|_X$.

This is very easy to prove by using the definitions and linearity, so I won’t redo this here.

Definition.
Let $X$ be a vector space over $\Bbb{F}$. Two norms $\rho_1,\rho_2$ are said to be equivalent if they induce the same topology on $X$.

You can easily check that this condition is equivalent to saying $\text{id}:(X,\rho_1)\to (X,\rho_2)$ is a homeomorphism. Since the identity map is linear in both directions, using the above characterization of continuity (the last bullet point), we have that $\rho_1,\rho_2$ are equivalent norms if and only if there exist $m,M>0$ such that for all $x\in X$, we have $m\rho_1(x)\leq \rho_2(x)\leq M\rho_1(x)$, i.e the ratio $\frac{\rho_2}{\rho_1}$ (defined away from the origin) is bounded above and below by positive numbers.

With those preliminaries out of the way, let us also assume the result that $\Bbb{F}^n$ with the Euclidean norm $\|x\|_2:=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2}$ satisfies the Heine-Borel property (look up the proof in Rudin). Now we prove a bunch of results

Theorem 1. (Equivalence of norms in $\Bbb{F}^n$)
All norms on $\Bbb{F}^n$ are equivalent.

Let $\rho$ be any norm on $\Bbb{F}^n$; I will show it is equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_2$ (this is enough since equivalence of norms is an equivalence relation). To do this, we first show $\rho:(\Bbb{F}^n,\|\cdot\|_2)\to [0,\infty)$ is continuous: for any $x,y\in\Bbb{F}^n$, we have
\begin{align}
|\rho(x)-\rho(y)|&\leq \rho(x-y)\tag{reverse triangle inequality}\\
&\leq\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|\rho(e_i)\tag{triangle inequality}\\
&\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\rho(e_i)\right)\cdot \|x-y\|_2.
\end{align}
This actually shows $\rho$ is Lipschitz, and hence continuous. Since the unit sphere $S=\{x\in\Bbb{F}^n\,:\, \|x\|_2=1\}$ is closed and bounded, it is compact by Heine-Borel. Now, $\rho$ is a positive, continuous function on $S$, so by the extreme-value theorem (a consequence of compactness), it has a positive minimum and maximum on $S$, call them $m,M$ respectively. By scaling, it follows that for all $x\in\Bbb{F}^n$, we have $m\|x\|_2\leq \rho(x)\leq M\|x\|_2$, thus proving that $\rho$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ are equivalent.

Corollary 1.
Let $(X,\rho)$ be any $n$-dimensional normed vector space over $\Bbb{F}$. Then every linear isomorphism $T:\Bbb{F}^n\to X$ is a homeomorphism.

Recall I already proved all norms on $\Bbb{F}^n$ are equivalent (i.e they all give the same topology), which is why I don’t have to specify which norm I’m using, so I’ll just denote it as $\|\cdot\|$. Then, by injectivity of $T$, we have that $\rho\circ T$ is a norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$, and thus there exist $m,M>0$ such that for all $x\in\Bbb{F}^n$, $m\|x\|\leq \rho(T(x))\leq M\|x\|$. The upper inequality shows that $T:(\Bbb{F}^n,\|\cdot\|)\to (X,\rho)$ is continuous (using the characterization of the last bullet point). The lower inequality is equivalent to saying that for all $\xi\in X$, $\|T^{-1}(\xi)\|\leq \frac{1}{m}\rho(\xi)$, i.e it is equivalent (again by the last bullet point above) to continuity of $T^{-1}:(X,\rho)\to (\Bbb{F}^n,\|\cdot\|)$. Hence, $T$ is a homeomorphism.

Corollary 2.
Every finite-dimensional normed vector space $(X,\rho)$ over $\Bbb{F}$ has the Heine-Borel property.

Fix a linear isomorphism $T:(\Bbb{F}^n,\|\cdot\|)\to (X,\rho)$. By corollary $1$, this is a homeomorphism. Hence, if $C\subset X$ is closed, then $T^{-1}(C)$ is closed; also if $C$ is bounded then (by continuity of $T^{-1}$ and the last bullet point above) $T^{-1}(C)$ is also bounded. Hence, by Heine-Borel in $\Bbb{F}^n$, we have that $T^{-1}(C)$ is compact. Thus, $C=T[T^{-1}(C)]$ being the continuous image of a compact set is compact.

That answers your question of proving Heine-Borel for arbitrary finite-dimensional normed vector spaces (I’m sure we could streamline the answer, but I wanted to break it up into smaller chunks). But while we’re here, lets prove some more standard results along these lines

Theorem 2.
Every finite-dimensional normed vector space is complete, and every linear map from a finite-dimensional normed vector space into an arbitrary normed vector space is continous.

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional normed vector space over $\Bbb{F}$. Fix any linear isomorphism $T:\Bbb{F}^n\to X$. We know by corollary (1) that $T$ is a homeomorphism, and Rudin proves (or leaves as an exercise) that $\Bbb{F}^n$ is complete; thus $X$ must be complete as well (in fact more generally if $E,F$ are normed vector spaces and $T:E\to F$ is a linear homeomorphism, and one of them, say $E$, is complete, then so is the other one: start with a Cauchy-sequence in $F$, then apply $T^{-1}$ to get a sequence in $E$, and using the last bullet point and continuity of $T^{-1}$ show that this is a Cauchy-sequence in $E$. Conclude). I leave these details to you.
Finally, let $X,Y$ be normed vector spaces, with $X$ $n$-dimensional, and $T:X\to Y$ linear. Fix any linear isomorphism $f:\Bbb{F}^n\to X$. Then, for all $x\in \Bbb{F}^n$
\begin{align}
\|(T\circ f)(x)\|_Y&\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\|(T\circ f)(e_i)\|_Y\cdot |x_i|\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\|(T\circ f)(e_i)\|_Y\right)\cdot \|x\|_2.
\end{align}
So, by the last bullet point, this proves $T\circ f$ is continuous, and since $f$ is a homeomorphism, it follows $T$ itself is continuous, thus completing the proof of theorem 2.

Corollary.
All norms on a finite-dimensional vector space are equivalent.

This follows trivially from the theorem since if $X$ is finite-dimensional and $\rho_1,\rho_2$ are any two norms, then the identity map $\text{id}:(X,\rho_1)\to (X,\rho_2)$ is linear, with finite-dimensional domain, so is continuous. Reversing the roles of $1,2$ shows that it is continuous in the other direction as well, hence it is a homeomorphism.

btw having proved theorem 1 (equivalence of norms in $\Bbb{F}^n$) there is some flexibility here in regard to the order in which to prove the remaining facts, and I encourage you to play around with different orders of things (and you could also merge various proofs so you have fewer statements to remember (the most commonly used ones are theorem 2 and the final corollary anyway)).

Thanks! It never struck me to prove equivalence of norms on $\mathbb{F}^n$ first. Just a small clarification- in the last line of the part where you show Lipschitzness of $\rho$, do you get $(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \rho^2(e_i))^{\frac{1}{2}}$  (by Cauchy-Schwarz) instead of what you've suggested? It doesn't change anything, of course, but I just thought I'd ask.

Cauchy-Schwarz works as well, but I just used the more elementary bound that for all $i$, we have $|x_i-y_i|\leq |x-y|_2$.

Ah, yes. Thanks! :)
